# Thymeleaf dropdown selection save Entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, thymeleaf

I want to add new Car from dropdown menu. I want to get the details about the choosen item. This is my Car entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "CAR")
public class Car {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    private Brand marka;
    
    @Column(name = "MODEL", nullable = false, length = 400)
    private String model;

    @Column(name = "YIL", nullable = false, length = 400)
    private int year;

    @Column(name = "KM", nullable = false, length = 400)
    private int km;

    @Column(name = "COST", nullable = false, length = 400)
    private int cost;
```

This is controller (new and save) :

```
@GetMapping("/new")
    public String add(Model model) {
        List<Brand> listbrand = brandService.listAll();
        model.addAttribute("listbrand", listbrand);
        model.addAttribute("car", new Car());
        return "new";
    }

     @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveCar(@ModelAttribute("car") Car car, Model model) {
    System.out.println(model);
    Brand brandget = (Brand) model.getAttribute("marka.value");
    System.out.println(brandget);
    //car.setMarka(brandService.get(brand.getId()));
    carService.save(car);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

And this is thymeleaf :

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/save}" th:object="${car}" method="post">


            <div class="form-group blu-margin">
            <label class="form-label"> MARKA </label>
            <select class="form-control" th:field="${marka}"  id="dropOperator">
                <option value="0">select brand</option>
                <option  th:each="brand : ${marka}" th:value="${brand}" th:text="${brand.brandName}"></option>
            </select>
        </div>

            <div alight="left">

                <tr>
                    <label class="form-label" >MODEL</label>
                    <td><input type="text" th:field="*{model}" class="form-control" placeholder="MODEL" /></td>
                </tr>
            </div>

            <div alight="left">
                <tr>
                    <label class="form-label" >YIL</label>
                    <td><input type="text" th:field="*{year}" class="form-control" placeholder="YIL" /></td>
                </tr>
            </div>

            <div alight="left">
                <tr>
                    <label class="form-label" >KM</label>
                    <td>

                        <input type="text" th:field="*{km}" class="form-control" placeholder="KM" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </div>

            <div alight="left">
                <tr>
                    <label class="form-label" >ÜCRET</label>
                    <td>

                        <input type="text" th:field="*{cost}" class="form-control" placeholder="ÜCRET" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </div>

            <br>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Save</button> </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

Console says Field 'marka' doesn't have a default value. How can i put a value to field marka from dropdown menu. And what it does now, it doesn't even returns back to default value.

Answer (score 1):

I think your select field is wrong. It should be * instead of $. And also "marka id" should be placed there as a field. Replace this:

```
<select class="form-control" th:field="${listbrand}"  id="dropOperator">
```

With this:

```
<select class="form-control" th:field="*{marka.id}" id="dropOperator">
```

Comment: It says: Bean property 'id' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to add getters and setters for Brand class? That id field must have a getter and setter so that spring can bind them.